# Negative px or large numbered px - which is better

Tags: html, css

I need to move text from bottom to top , so i can do it by 2 ways, either top or bottom.

If i use top, I have to use negative px, for bottom I have to give more number px

Which is better to use generally - **negative px** or **more number px** [ top: -22px; or bottom: 103px; ]?

```
    position: absolute;
    top: -22px;   /*or bottom: 103px;*/
    right: 15px;
    text-align: right;    
}
```

Comment: I would choose top version, becouse smaller numbers seems more clear to me. I don't think there is real time-saving difference between them. Use what you want.

Comment: I usually use closest edge

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @StefanStefko please post your comment as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would choose top version, becouse smaller numbers seems more clear to me. I don't think there is real time-saving difference between them. Use what you want.

Comment: Right. Performance wise it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to move text from bottom to top

If you are animating via CSS, you are better off using

```
transform: translateY(y);
```

rather than animating using `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left`.

Here are the 5 `translate` properties:

- `transform: translate(x,y)`
- `transform: translateX(x)`
- `transform: translateY(y)`
- `transform: translateZ(z)`
- `transform: translate3d(x,y,z)`

---

**Further Reading:**

- [*A Tale of Animation Performance*](http://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/) by Chris Coyier (Dec 20, 2012)
- [*Why Moving Elements With Translate() Is Better Than Pos:abs Top/left*](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) by Paul Irish (Dec 20, 2012)

Comment: Thats really very valuable information, Thanks a lot.....